# SQl query for (person,theatre) relation

Tags: sql, database

I recently appeared for an interview and was asked to write SQL query for this question-

There is table visit(person,theatre) which denotes that a person p visits a theatre t. Now a person p1 is considered to be more movie lover if he visits every theatre that another person p2 visits. I was supposed to write an SQL query to find the most movie loving person (a person who is more movie lover than every other person).

I really had no idea about how to answer it. I mumbled about using sub queries and aggregate operators but couldnt answer it.

Can anyone tell me what the query be?

**NOTE:** I was told that I cannot use recursion here

Comment: I am not sure what the requirement is?? DO you simply have to count how many theaters a person has visited and the greates movie lover is the guy with the maximum of theaters visited? That would be simple.

Comment: It's the example of partion order. What should we do if Person1 visited Theater1 and Theater2 and Person2 visited Theater2, Theater3, Theater4?

Comment: @ivicaa what the question says is that if P1 is the greatest movie lover than he should have visited every theatre which other persons have visited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description is *quite vague*, so if we state the problem as "is there any person who has visited all the theaters all other persons have" we can put it like that:

```
select v.person
  from visit v
 where v.theatre = all ( 
         select vt.theatre
           from visit vt)
```

Comment: I understand the description is vague but that was all they provided me during the interview. I asked for more explanation but interviewer said that this information is more than required to answer

Comment: @user2916886: Often when on interview you can earn additional points if you say "there's an example of partial order, let's check the details: if P1 visited T1, T2 and P2 visited T2 and T3 none should be returned as answer; in case of tie, e.g. P1 - T1; P2 - T1 both should be returned. Do I understand you correct?". I often take interviews and often give vague tasks on purpouse to see what kind of questions a candidate would ask me

Answer (score 0):

Description is vague, but something like

```
select person, count(*) as cnt
from visit
group by person
order by cnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select person,count(theatre) from Visit Group By person having max(count(theatre)))
```

Comment: I think the first assumption of taking three tables itself is wrong. The question specifies that there is one table visit(person,theatre).